# pyaudio installation error ( #include <stdio.h> command 'clang' failed with exit status 1)

Tags: python-3.x, xcode, pip, clang, pyaudio

I'm trying to install pyaudio in mac having python 64 bit, using the command "`pip3 install pyaudio`", by getting the below error.

```
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
        Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: '/Users/sambitkumar/Documents/Learn/Python Packages/speech/venv/bin/python3' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-install-sq4k9xkw/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-install-sq4k9xkw/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-record-0v8uniq2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/sambitkumar/Documents/Learn/Python Packages/speech/venv/include/site/python3.7/pyaudio'
             cwd: /private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-install-sq4k9xkw/pyaudio/
        Complete output (16 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
        copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
        running build_ext
        building '_portaudio' extension
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/src
        clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/sambitkumar/Documents/Learn/Python Packages/speech/venv/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
        src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
        #include <stdio.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~
        1 error generated.
        error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users/sambitkumar/Documents/Learn/Python Packages/speech/venv/bin/python3' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-install-sq4k9xkw/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-install-sq4k9xkw/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kr/jr2wrc015pz1clvbqvwr1lhh0000gn/T/pip-record-0v8uniq2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/sambitkumar/Documents/Learn/Python Packages/speech/venv/include/site/python3.7/pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried the below solutions but none of them could help me in installing the package successfully.

1. brew install portaudio (It's already installed)
2. pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio (same error as mentioned above)
3. xcode-select --install (It fails saying this is either already installed or not required any more.)

Any suggestion to install the package successfully?